# Is there a way to watch multiple textboxes to see if the text changed?

Tags: vb.net

I have about 15 text boxes  and instead of going to the event handler on each one and enabling a button on a change..

For example:

```
    Private Sub txtIsbnUpc_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles txtIsbnUpc.TextChanged

        cmdSearchresults.enabled = true
    End Sub
```

Instead of going through each one and typing that is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you extend the `Handles` list and handle all textBoxes events in one handler?

```
Private Sub txtIsbnUpc_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles txtIsbnUpc.TextChanged, txt2.TextChanaged, txt3.TextChanged
```

You can use `sender` to check which textBox fired that handler, if it's needed for your logic.

Comment: +1 can also be done in the designer. Properties window, event view. It alters the Handles clause for you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the beauty of .NET is the ability to wire the same event handler to more than one control.
You could assign the same handler to the TextChanged event of all your 15 textbox.
So no need to code 15 event handler with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, list your other textboxes in the "Handles" section of  your event signature:

```
Private Sub txtIsbnUpc_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtIsbnUpc.TextChanged, Handles txt2.TextChanged,Handles txt3.TextChanged, etc....

sender.enabled = true

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even use addhandler for each text box and lead it to other function created by you with argument to text change of textbox....