# When any of the textboxes changes (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner to VB and I'm looking to optimize my code a little. I have 9 textboxes, and every time one of them changes I run a Subroutine based on it's content. Is there a way to make it, perhaps with a for loop, go through all of the 9 textboxes and register when any of them changes. Here's ..my code looks like at the moment...

```
Private Sub tbBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbBox1.TextChanged
    checkInput(tbBox1, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub tbBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbBox2.TextChanged
    checkInput(tbBox2, 0, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub tbBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbBox3.TextChanged
    checkInput(tbBox3, 0, 2)
End Sub
```

..etc

Comment: Could you explain what are the parameters passed to checkInput (the last two)?

Comment: You can make one `TextChanged` method and have all the TextBoxes use it - you don't have to write the same method for each control.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to watch multiple textboxes to see if the text changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759669/is-there-a-way-to-watch-multiple-textboxes-to-see-if-the-text-changed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a separate handler for each text box. A single handler method can handle all of them. If you need a value for each text box to pass into your `checkInput` method, just use the `Tag` property of each text box.

```
Private Sub TextBoxChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbBox1.TextChanged, tbBox2.TextChanged, tbBox3.TextChanged 'etc.
    checkInput(sender, 0, sender.Tag)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try multiple Handles:

```
Private Sub tbBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
                              tbBox1.TextChanged, _
                              tbBox2.TextChanged, _
                              tbBox3.TextChanged
  checkInput(sender, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that.  Is there a C# equivalent, out of curiousity?

Comment: @Tim no there isn't.  The advantage VB.Net has here is this simple syntax plus you easily can see the event was attached.  In C#, you don't always know (especially from new users on Stack Overflow) whether or not the event is even wired up.

Comment: @Tim I would say that you can get the same effect in C#. That is the same method can handle the event for several controls, it's just that in C# you don't have a Handles clause on the method declaration to decide which events to handle, instead you can specify the handler for the events separately.